# TSQL Is it possible to do a NULLIF where a column is less than 15% of another column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a large query that I'm trying to edit to insert 40ish columns into a database at a specific time in the day for trending reasons.

Currently the query is doing a `NULLIF(Linespeed, 0)` but I'd much rather it work in the way that would be something like

```
NULLIF(Linespeed > Linespeed_Target * 15)
```

(I know this doesn't work). I can't quite figure out how I would do a case statement for this. I also don't think I can do it in the where clause because I have another column that looks for where Linespeed is any value.

Code here:

```
Nullif(Round(Avg(Nullif(Linespeed, 0)) / Avg(LineSpeed_Target), 2), 0) as 'LS OEE'
```

The reason I can't use a where clause:

```
NullIF(Round(Cast(count(NULLIF(0 ,LineSpeed)) / Cast(Count(Linespeed) as float) as float), 2), 0) as 'Avail OEE'
```

[Results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT9Zm.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what results you are trying to generate.

Comment: FWIW `NULLIF(x, 0)` is just shorthand for `CASE WHEN x = 0 THEN NULL ELSE x END`, and `CASE` is the more general form that would allow any condition. For referring to values computed elsewhere, use a subquery or CTE (`WITH`), the latter generally being easier for building up complex queries in steps.

Comment: Sorry, I edited in a picture of the results I'm currently getting.  The column LS AVG should be an AVG of values when value is above 15% of the linespeed target so it doesn't count against performance and instead affects the availability of the machine.

The LS Avg should be close to 800 but I am currently avging in values that are lower than the threshold I want to add.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> The column LS AVG should be an AVG of values when value is above 15% of the linespeed target

That would be:

```
avg(case when linespeed > linespeed_target * 0.15 then linespeed end)
```

The `case` expression returns `null` for values that do not meet the condition, which `avg()` ignores.

Comment: Well *almost* ignores, you'll still get the obnoxious (but fortunately only informational) "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation". Rewriting to avoid that is seldom worth it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen actually pointed out the solution to me!

What I ended up using is this:

```
Nullif(Round(Avg((Case when Linespeed < Linespeed_Target * .10 then NULL Else Linespeed End)) / Avg(LineSpeed_Target), 2), 0) as 'LS OEE',
```